# How to flag edits?

Tags: support

How does one bring inappropriate or malicious editing to the attention of moderators?  I know the question or answer itself can be flagged, but that's not what I'm asking about.  I don't want to flag the content of the answer, especially since I will have fixed it anyway.  I want to bring the malicious behavior to the attention of the moderators.  There seems to be no "flag" button in a particular edit.  I'd expect to find it right next to "roll back" if there was one.

### Background

There have been a few cases recently where a user has edited answers knowing full well he was changing author intent (the author explicitly told him this previously).  The purpose was clearly to annoy the author, and the edits were even re-done after having been rolled back.  In other cases, a typo or two were fixed, but then that used as a opportunity to change known author intent.  Since this continues to happen, I looked for a way to flag the edit itself, but found no such mechanism.

How should I handle this if I encounter another such deliberately malicious edit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can flag the post for moderator attention with a custom message and include the revision number.

Comment: If you just say "malicious edit", we'll look at the full edit history anyway.

Comment: In addition, if a post has too many rollbacks, the system automatically generates a flag.

Comment: @NickAlexeev That's great, but is only applicable if all malicious edits would be on the same posts. Is there some mechanic in place flagging users with multiple malicious edits? That would be highly impractical to implement.

Comment: @Mast if you notice one user making many malicious edits, you can flag any of his posts and explain the situation. I'm not sure if the system automatically raises some flag when a user has many rejected edits.